# Cumulative total of columns in a matrix or table

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, summation

I have the following:

```
matrix1 = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}, {m, n, o, p}}
```

(Note that it's the data that matters, not the fact it's defined as a matrix. Could be a table, could be a list.)

I want to create a cumulative sum, so that each entry is the sum of all data in that row up to and including column `n`, which is the column where the sum is to be placed. In other words, I want

```
matrix2 = {{a, a + b, a + b + c, a + b + c + d}, {e, e + f, e + f + g, e + f + g + h}, {i, i + j, i + j + k, i + j + k + l}, {m, m + n, 
m + n + o, m + n + o + p}}
```

I assume there must be a way to do this using `Total[matrix1 ,{2}]` combined with some way to specify the number of columns to sum - maybe `Range`...? Or should I be using `Part` and `Span`? If so, how?

Can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I first came up with:

```
FoldList[Plus, #[[1]], Rest[#]] & /@ matrix
```

Then read the documentation for Accumulate, which says it is equivalent to:

```
Rest[FoldList[Plus, 0, #]] & /@ matrix1
```

One nice thing about these approaches is they generalize beyond sums:

```
FoldList[Times, #[[1]], Rest[#]] & /@ matrix1
Rest[FoldList[Times, 1, #]] & /@ matrix1
```

Comment: In more recent versions of *Mathematica*, `FoldList[Times, #] &` is equivalent to `FoldList[Times, #[[1]], Rest[#]] &`.  (I forget exactly when they added that syntactic sugar.)

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun, another approach using matrix-matrix multiplication:

```
acc = matrix1.UpperTriangularize[ConstantArray[1, {1, 1} Dimensions[matrix1][[2]]]];
acc // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a & a+b & a+b+c & a+b+c+d \\
>  e & e+f & e+f+g & e+f+g+h \\
>  i & i+j & i+j+k & i+j+k+l \\
>  m & m+n & m+n+o & m+n+o+p \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

As alternative to `Accumulate[matrix1]`, you could use

```
acc = LowerTriangularize[ConstantArray[1, {1, 1} Dimensions[matrix1[[1]]]].matrix1;
acc // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a & b & c & d \\
>  a+e & b+f & c+g & d+h \\
>  a+e+i & b+f+j & c+g+k & d+h+l \\
>  a+e+i+m & b+f+j+n & c+g+k+o & d+h+l+p \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

I would not advise to use these in practice as they have computational complexity $O(n^3)$ while the methods involving `Accumulate` have only complexity $O(n^2)$.

Comment: Dear @Richard, you can only mark a single answer as _the_ answer to your question (although you can upvote as many as you like). In this case, I would recommend to mark kglr's post as answer as it is (i) more concise and (ii) more efficient than mine.

Comment: Clever. `Accumulate` is probably the standard way, but I do prefer/like Linear Algebra solutions.

Answer (score 6):

```
Accumulate /@ matrix1
```

produces

```
{{a, a + b, a + b + c, a + b + c + d}, {e, e + f, e + f + g, 
  e + f + g + h}, {i, i + j, i + j + k, i + j + k + l}, {m, m + n, 
  m + n + o, m + n + o + p}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mx = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}, {m, n, o, p}};

mx // TableForm
```

[image]

Using `ArrayReduce` (new in 12.2)

Accumulate rows

```
ArrayReduce[Accumulate, mx, 2] // TableForm
```

[image]

Accumulate columns

```
ArrayReduce[Accumulate, mx, 1] // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
mx = {{a, b, c, d}, {e, f, g, h}, {i, j, k, l}, {m, n, o, p}};

mx2 = {{a, a + b, a + b + c, a + b + c + d}, {e, e + f, e + f + g, e + f + g + h}, 
      {i, i + j, i + j + k, i + j + k + l}, {m, m + n, m + n + o, m + n + o + p}};
```

A variation using `FoldList`:

```
FoldList[Apply[Plus]@*Flatten@*List, Nothing, #] & /@ mx === mx2

(*True*)
```